# How use todonotes without adding items to Todo list

Tags: todonotes

I want to have two types of [todonotes](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf):

1. Type1: note goes to todo list (color red)
2. Type1: note doesn't go to todo list (color yellow)

So when I run `\listoftodos`, I see only type 1 todo items.

Here is my code that define two type of todo items:

```
\ifsetDraft
    \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
    \newcommand{\type1}[1]{\todo[size=\small,inline,color=red!40]{#1}}
    \newcommand{\type2}[1]{\todo[size=\small,inline,color=yellow!40]{#1}}

\else
    \newcommand{\type1}[1]{}
    \newcommand{\type2}[1]{}
    \newcommand{\listoftodos}{}
\fi
```

Is there any way to improve code above and add this function?

or maybe there is a way to call `\listoftodos` and only use Type1 todo items such as `\listoftodos[type1]`

Comment: Can you make a MWE?

Answer (score 3):

The `todonotes` package offers a solution with the `nolist` option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
\listoftodos
\section*{First section}
Some text\todo{Do this.}\\
More text\todo{More to do}\\
Even more text\todo[nolist]{So much work to do!}\\
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]